# Is there a word for the condition of being infested with ticks?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, medical

Is there a word or term for the state of a human or animal infested with ticks?

Mainly just curious.

Examples:

> He's suffering from ______.
>
> Don't get near him: he has _____.

Comment: Since the answer you said "is exactly what [you] were looking for" does not answer the original question at all, I took the liberty of rephrasing it to fit lbf's answer. If you really did mean something else and wanted a word for the person instead of the condition, feel free to rephrase and explain.

Comment: Schrodinger's Ticked: You're both Ticked on AND Ticked off.

Comment: If I were looking to be somewhat humorous and non-technical, I'd personally say *lousy with ticks* just because I like using the more literal meaning of *lousy*.

Comment: /me expects the etymology of "ticked" to appear here.

Comment: See also https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/scabies/

Comment: "Lousy" means "infested with lice", but I've heard it used to describe infestation. For example, "My cupboards are lousy with ants"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ectoparasitism [TFD](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/ectoparasitism) is the medical term:

> the state in which the ectoparasite [ticks, lice] are living on the
>   surface of the host's body.

He went to the doctor with ticks, and was diagnosed with **ectoparasitosis.**

Answer (score 34):

I don't think there is a word that refers to possessing ticks as a condition, but you could use "tick-ridden" or "tick-infested" as an adjective:

> The dog is tick-ridden.

Comment: +1 We may need noun forms *tick-infestation* / *tick-riddenness* (?) rather. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick_infestation

Comment: It looks like the question's been edited since you answered; you may need to edit to fit the new example sentences in the question. (But usually you'd just say "he/it has ticks".)

Answer (score 8):

For the second sentence example you can simply use "ticks" - "don't go near him he has ticks", just as you would with lice or fleas.

If sticking to a single word is not essential you might want to be more specific and say "an infestation of ticks" - to make it clear that the subject has a large number of the parasites, not just one or two.

"an infestation of ticks" could also work in the first sentence example. "He's suffering from an infestation of ticks"

Comment: "He's suffering from ticks" works fine also.

Comment: @Timbo I'm not so sure , that sounds slightly wrong to me, I've  never heard it used like that (though on googling it I can see quite a few examples of that phrase, which do sound fine, so maybe you are right)

Comment: I wouldn't choose that construction (I'd pick the more informal "Watch out! He's got ticks!") but I would understand it if I heard it.

Comment: Ironically, you can't use the proper term for an infestation of lice as "lousy" is now used only in the figurative sense (as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ticky):

ticky -er/-est

: affected or infested with or full of ticks

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking for an informal way of saying it, you pretty much have the most natural way already:

> "he is tick-infested" or "he is infested with ticks".

Saying "He *has* ..." is asking for a formal medical condition, like diabetes. The most informal of this would be

> "He has a problem with ticks" or "He has a lot of ticks".